# Mail does not sent in Squirrelmail in Localhost

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, mail-server, webmail, squirrelmail

I have recently make a web mail server in ubuntu 14.04 LTS .
I have complete all the steps and configuration of postfix , dovecot and squirrelmail . 
Now I'm log into squirrelmail and send a mail to another user. The mail is going to the sent mail box that seems that the mail is sent. 
But when log into that user account where the mail sent , there is no mail in inbox. 
any solution ?? 
-- my english may be not so good , sorry for that. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks . At last I can do it . 
Your thinking is right .. I have configured wrong path in dovecot for mail inbox .
In **/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf** in mail_location i put maildir:~/mail 
the correct configuration is

protocols = imap pop3

mail_location =  maildir:~/Maildir

Answer (score 0):

Check what happens when you send the mail in the postfix log. For ubuntu 14.04 it probably is in /var/log/mail.log.

Comment: here is the \var\log\mail.log

the log is huge so I cannot directly give here .
here is the link. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jh29z8s8ebx75qx/mail%20log.txt?dl=0

Comment: this will apppear when use tail commnad
root@mail:/# sudo tail /var/log/mail.log
Jul 22 11:18:26 mail dovecot: imap(user2): Disconnected: Logged out in=117 out=1535
Jul 22 11:25:51 mail dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Jul 22 11:25:51 mail dovecot: anvil: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Jul 22 11:25:51 mail dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Jul 22 11:25:51 mail dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.9 starting up (core dumps disabled)

Comment: From the log file I would guess that postfix correctly delivers it to a maildir in some specific path but dovecot is configured to a different maildir and therefor never sees the new mail.

Not possible to say what exactly is wrong without knowing how exactly you've configured stuff. Mail delivery from postfix to dovecot can be done in a lot of different ways.

Comment: Thanks . At last I can do it . 
Your thinking is right .. I have configured wrong path in dovecot for mail inbox .